# Why do events with arguments of custom types appear fully-encoded in Tx Logs?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, events, logs

You can observe the behavior via the following contract which I've deployed to Polygon Mumbai at [0x33c059160280a45725d9509c120c6b30a44a61a4](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x33c059160280a45725d9509c120c6b30a44a61a4):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract EventWithCustomTypeArg
{
    struct Custom
    {
        uint value;
    }

    Custom private c;

    event CustomValueSet(Custom _c);
    event CustomValueSet(uint _value);

    function setCustomValue(uint _value) public
    {
        c.value = _value;
        emit CustomValueSet(c);
        emit CustomValueSet(_value);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've executed the setCustomValue() function, passing it `5` as the argument. As a result, both the `event CustomValueSet(Custom _c)` and  the `event CustomValueSet(uint _value)` have been emitted (in this order), but while the latter appears fully decoded/human-readable in the Tx Logs, the `Custom` argument, the argument value **and** the event name itself of the former are encoded:
[image]

Why is that?
I can imagine why the argument of the custom type appears encoded, but why isn't the event name human-readable, at least?

Answer (score 2):

Polygonscan or other blockchain developers are not necessarily the most user-friendly way to decode complex blockchain data, such as the custom events data that you have there.

However, it is possible to decode the data using API providers, such as Moralis. You can use [`getContractEvents`](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-contract-events) API here to do so. So simply you'll need to [sign up](https://admin.moralis.io/register) and get Moralis API Key, then install Moralis SDK

```sh
npm install moralis
```

and copy the code as follows:

```js
import Moralis from 'moralis';

try {
  await Moralis.start({
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY"
  });

  const response = Moralis.EvmApi.events.getContractEvents({
    "chain": "mumbai",
    "topic": "0xd43c5030eb09cb86062bca5370e1ef5ce38fdc025e9c26114b94d6d1cbdcd2ed",
    "address": "0x33C059160280A45725D9509C120c6B30A44A61A4",
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "indexed": false,
        "internalType": "struct EventWithCustomTypeArg.Custom",
        "name": "_c",
        "type": "tuple"
      }
    ],
    "name": "CustomValueSet",
    "type": "event"
  });

  console.log(response.raw);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

and the response should be the decoding of your event data like this

```json
{
  "total": null,
  "page": 0,
  "page_size": 100,
  "result": [
    {
      "transaction_hash": "0x1bbe419ef6c9ca5ce3dc452309f73fe80503d2f10672be165c6378fed47b7448",
      "address": "0x33c059160280a45725d9509c120c6b30a44a61a4",
      "block_timestamp": "2023-03-09T14:33:08.000Z",
      "block_number": "32902536",
      "block_hash": "0x078d29120118dbc93a05dd018ee97c6d6473476203407b4c0f90e1e38c5846cb",
      "data": {
        "_c": [
          "5"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps out! Let me know if you have any questions!

P.S. I work at Moralis